# In a state $\alpha \vert HL \rangle + \beta \vert VR \rangle$ can a particle be measured in the $\{|L\rangle,|R\rangle\}$ basis?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, measurement

Given a pair of entangled particles:
$\alpha \vert HL \rangle + \beta \vert VR \rangle$

where:

1. $\alpha^2 + \beta^2=1$
2. $H$ and $V$ are orthonormal vectors.
3. $L$ and $R$ are orthogonal vectors (but not necessarily orthonormal).

Is it possible to measure one of the particles in $L$ and $R$ basis using a polarizer (without any normalization etc.)? Or does quantum mechanics forbids it? And if yes, does the probability of it being $L$ or $R$ given by $\alpha^2$ and $\beta^2$ respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overall state must have unit norm, i.e. for $|\psi\rangle=\alpha  |HL\rangle+\beta|VR\rangle$ we should have $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle=1$. If I understood the question, by your assumption $\langle H |V\rangle=0$, and $\langle L |R\rangle=0$, hence
$$\langle\psi|\psi\rangle=|\alpha|^2\langle H|H\rangle \langle L|L\rangle +|\beta|^2\langle V|V\rangle \langle R|R\rangle=1$$

Assuming further that $|H\rangle$ and $|V\rangle$ have unit norm and $|\beta|^2=1-|\alpha|^2$  this reduces to
$$|\alpha|^2\langle L|L\rangle +(1-|\alpha|^2)\langle R|R\rangle=1$$
Although for states $|L\rangle$ and $|R\rangle$ of unit norm this constraint is satisfied, they do not need to have unit norm, but only subject to satisfy the constraint.

With all that said, defining normalized versions of $|R\rangle$, $|L\rangle$ and adjusting the coefficients $\alpha,\beta$ correspondingly would probably make the analysis much simpler.

----------(addition)

If the vectors $|L\rangle, |R\rangle$ are not normilized, then coefficients $|\alpha|^2, |\beta|^2$ in decomposition $|\psi\rangle=\alpha |L\rangle+\beta |L\rangle$ do not correspond to measurement probabilities. Consider a simple example $|L\rangle = \frac1{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle, |R\rangle = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}|1\rangle$ and
$$|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|L\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|R\rangle=\frac12|0\rangle+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|1\rangle$$
The actual measurement probabilities are $\frac14,\frac34$. It is not clear to me though why go into the trouble of working with non-normilized states at all in this context.

Comment: Hi, great analysis Nikita. Could you extend your reply to address the OP's question about measurement when states are not normalized and how this relates to completeness relation of projective measurements?

Comment: @MonteNero done.

Comment: @NikitaNemkov Thank you for the answer. understood quiet a bit. But I am still unclear about the central Q. As you mentioned in (addition) the $|L\rangle = \frac1{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle, |R\rangle = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}|1\rangle$. Thus, they are not normalized. But the probability we calculated is of $|0\rangle, |1\rangle$ by inserting the values and effectively normalizing. Is the calculation of probability and measurement only possible for $|0\rangle, |1\rangle$ but not for $|L\rangle, |R\rangle$. That was the original query and I am still unclear about it ?

Comment: I mean $|L\rangle, |R\rangle$ are vectors too even if not normalized. How can we measure their probability if at all possible and not $|0\rangle, |1\rangle$'s?

Comment: Two answers are possible: (1) state $\frac12|0\rangle$ is not a valid state (2) there is no difference between state $|0\rangle$ and state $\frac12|0\rangle$. I think (2) is more common, but depends on the conventions a bit. What is the difference between a system in state $|\psi\rangle$ and a system in state $\frac12|\psi\rangle$?

Comment: Let us go to the original Q. The state is: $\alpha \vert HL \rangle + \beta \vert VR \rangle$. If we measure one particle in $H/V$ the probabilities that the other particle is in state $L/R$ is $\alpha^2$, $\beta^2$ respectively (since the $H/V$ is orthonormal). That part to me is clear. But if we measure in the state $L/R$ then since $L/R$ are just orthogonal but not normal this probability calculation will not work! Hence the Q. I still am struggling that we can't measure in $L/R$ state as its not a valid state. I mean we can have such a pair, but don't know howto calculate probability!

Comment: If we say there is no difference b/w state $|0\rangle$ and $\frac12|0\rangle$ then the probability of other particle being in state $H/V$ must be $α2 , β2$ respectively? right?

Comment: @TheoryQuest1 For your original state $|\psi\rangle=\alpha |HL\rangle+\beta |VR\rangle$ the probability to find the first particle in state $|H\rangle$ is _not_ equal to $|\alpha|^2$, but to $|\alpha|^2 \langle L|L\rangle$. If your first particle is measured in state $|H\rangle$ the second is in (normalized) $|L\rangle$ with certainty. Unnormalized _vectors_ $|L\rangle, |R\rangle$ may be useful to keep in intermediate computations, but they are not valid states. And if you only work with normalized states, there is no ambiguity, right?

Comment: thank you! I am somewhat more clear but I will try to work though some examples and take some time to process it completely.. I understand with the normalized states part.. thank you for the patience once again.. :)